# Как сделать фильтр в Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, cms, joomla3

Как можно сделать фильтр Joomla как [на этом сайте](http://www.fitili.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&Itemid=10)?

"Сортировать: по цене · по названию · по калибру" - вот такой

Comment: Скидывать параметры запроса и сортировать в соответствии с ними?

Comment: @Alex78191 делаю так - `order by klv_1 ASC` но почему-то оно сортирует их не по порядку, а 5 5 5 10 10 10 10 2 2 2 8 8 8

Comment: Вы лучше бы показали SQL запрос, так легче помочь!